# shoutcast stream controlled through http requests

Tags: http, audio, shoutcast

so I am not even sure where to begin on this ... basically my friend wants me to set up a shoutcast audio stream but we need to be able to control what plays and when through http get or post requests. Does anyone know where to begin on setting this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool for this job is currently [Liquidsoap](http://savonet.sourceforge.net/).

It's a scripting language and framework for controlling your audio.  You can add HTTP endpoints to do whatever you script it to do.

A few cautions:

- Some functionality is notoriously unstable.  Test thoroughly, and for long periods of time before deploying.
- The [documentation](http://savonet.sourceforge.net/doc-svn/reference.html) isn't good.  There are a few of us here on Stack Overflow that answer questions with the [`liquidsoap` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liquidsoap), but the Savonet mailing list is far more active.
- Installation isn't fun.  I've found it to be nearly impossible under CentOS, and doable under Ubuntu with a bit of hacking around.  There are a lot of scripts online for installing it, depending on what modules you need.  I believe they are also shipping a Docker image now, which might be best.

If you can get past those items, then you're in good shape.  There are many stations that use Liquidsoap, and have for years without fail.  There are also some [radio automation packages built upon Liquidsoap](https://www.sourcefabric.org/en/airtime/).

### Alternative Option: VLC

VLC has a web interface that you can hook into.  It can also output to Icecast servers.  The big issue here is that metadata doesn't work.  But, this might be a more reliable and easier option depending on the specifics of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Liquidsoap is the way to go, but as stated above, it's cumbersome to install. An alternative is to use the **sc_trans** player, a native command line audio player for shoutcast.

Although sc_trans is a little bit deprecated, it does the job. Don't know why it's not supported anymore by shoutcast or winamp, but the following link provides versions for:

**sc_trans** for [MAC, Windows, Linux, BSD](http://mirror.lchost.net/download.nullsoft.com/shoutcast/tools/)